# Internet explorer won't sent special characters

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, browser, character-encoding

My website: www.egemen.dk

I'm developing a website and have problems with special characters on IE. On my website there is a dropdown box with a number of lastnames. These lastnames can contain special characters like ô, î,ö, etc. Everything works fine when getting these lastnames from database to build the dropdown and special characters are displayed correctly, however, the user should be able to select a lastname and perform a search. When selecting a lastname with special character, the code calls javascript method to connect to database. In FF and safari it works, but with IE it can't send these special characters correctly to the javascript. Any idea?

Javascript:

```
<script>
function searchUser(str)
{
    var call ="/Data/controller.php?cmd="+str;
    if(str == "searchByName"){
        call += "&name=" + document.getElementById("s_name").value;
        call += "&lname=" + document.getElementById("s_lname").value;
    }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET", call ,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1  /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

I have also tried with utf-8 as the charset in meta.

Comment: What version(s) of IE are you testing?

Comment: What does "not correctly" look like exactly? What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The values need to be URL encoded with [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
var call ="/Data/controller.php?cmd="+encodeURIComponent(str);
if(str == "searchByName"){
    call += "&name=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("s_name").value);
    call += "&lname=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("s_lname").value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When trying this the code wont compile. It gives an error.

Comment: @user2373787 double check your other code. There are no syntax errors in the answer. What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Something odd is going on, because browsers display the page using windows-1252 encoding, even though the page seems to have a `meta` tag that declares UTF-8 (and the HTTP headers do not specify encoding). The explanation is that if you check the code with a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/), you’ll see that there is typo in the tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8" />
```

The quotation mark before `utf-8` should be removed.

This affects the encoding of the form data when submitted. It is by default the same as the encoding of the page. It should be UTF-8 to ensure that all characters will be sent correctly.